# Cuando un elemento está activado en el Menu 1 y se cambia a Menu 2 no aparece activado

Tags: jquery, html, css

Al seleccionar el menú 1, aparece subrayado marcando que está seleccionado, pero al seleccionar el menú 2, sigue subrayando al menú 1.

Intenté que quede seleccionado cuando hago click en el menú 2 con `css(.selected:before)` pero no entiendo qué pasa.

Este es el código donde se ve la diferencia si hacen click en un menú o en el otro.

```js
$('ul.menu-lateral .sub-menu').hide(); //Ocultar hijos de forma predeterminada
 
 $('ul.menu-lateral li a').click(function(){
   
 $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
   
});


$('ul.menu-lateral > li').click(function(){
  $('ul.menu-lateral > li').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
  margin: 30px;
}

ul > li.selected:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  right: 0;
  top: 45px;
  margin: 3px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #F39323;
  width: 100px;
}

ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-menu" role="navigation">
    <ul class="menu-lateral">
        <li><a href="#"> MENU 1 </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"> SUB MENU 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#"> MENU 2 </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrias elaborar un poco mas?

Comment: @hackeman cuando click menu 2 no puede active con css(.selected:before) y no se que paso.

Comment: pienso que el problema es el position: absolute

Comment: @ReneLimon si en serio?

Comment: El valor `absolute` hace que la ubicación de un elemento sea relativo **al elemento padre más cercano** que tenga un `position: relative`. En tu caso no hay elementos con esa posición, por ende, el elemento `:before` será relativo al body. Lo que puedes hacer es adoptar la solución que te han dado o ponerle un `position: relative` al `li` y darle un top del alto del `li` + 10px para que quede la barra justo debajo de él. Mira [éste ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/0860vbLs/) para que te veas el efecto.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas!!

Tienes un error en tu CSS ya que estas posicionando en absolute lo cual se posiciona de acuerdo "a su ancestro mas cercano posicionado" eso quiere decir que tus valores left,top etc... comenzaran a moverse desde el valor del DOM ya que no tienes algún ancestro posicionado, de esta manera la linea de subrayado esta una sobre otra por eso no se ve, otra posible solución sería usar un margen bottom para subrayar el menú activo

Por otro lado puedes usar toggleClass en el mismo evento para desplegar los menús secundarios y al mismo tiempo colorear el subrayado el menú principal, te propongo la siguiente solución

```js
$('ul.menu-lateral .sub-menu').hide(); //Ocultar hijos de forma predeterminada

$('ul.menu-lateral li').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow')
  $(this).children(':first').toggleClass('selected')
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
  margin: 30px;
}

.selected{
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-menu" role="navigation">
    <ul class="menu-lateral">
        <li class=""><a href="#"> MENU 1 </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#"> SUB MENU 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class=""><a href="#"> MENU 2 </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">SUB MENU 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```